# Extracting data and do calculation from multiple CSV file and compile the calculation values into one file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have written a code for extracting data from a single csv file and performing a set of calculation to output 1 result. What I want to do is I will like to be able to running this file over a set of 20 csv raw data files, perform the calculation to get the results for each files and compile all these results into a single matrix.

for example, at the end, I will have a 20 by 1 matrix , with each row representing the result from each csv files for 20 csv raw files.

Here is the matlab code so far for a single file.

```
filename = 'some_file.csv'
delimiter = ',';
startRow = 19;
formatSpec = '%*s%*s%f%f%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue'      ,NaN,'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
fclose(fileID);

% extracted data into variable time and v

time = dataArray{:, 1};
v = dataArray{:, 2};

clearvars filename delimiter startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;

% Start of calculation

I = v.*2000; % sensitivity 0.5mA/V
I_2 = I.^2;
current_parameter = trapz(time,I_2);

% Parameters, would like to set this up as input with 4 variable
h = 25; 
w = 5;  
t = 2;  
L_prime = 0.794193406;

%Results
Ibit(1) = 0.5*current_parameter*L_prime

end
```

What I want is that I will like to run this files in a loop and call as a function where i can input specific parameters (4 variables) for each set of csv files. the result is the Ibit where 1 Ibit correspond to 1 csv file. I would like to compile this variable for the set of files i have.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
list=dir('home/Desktop/csv_folder/*.csv'); % gives a structure with all .csv files info
ibit=zeros(size(list));
for i=1:length(list)
filename=list(i).name;
ibit(i)=csv_operation(filename,h(i),w(i),t(i),L_prime(i)); % where h,w,t,L_prime are vectors with input
                                               % parameters in order for the filelist

end
```

Comment: @AKSG, if this solved your problem, clicking the tick mark to the left side of the answer is a nice way to say thank you =)